# Jquery ajax fail when calling rest webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

I have a set of REST URIs that i can access after authenticating on the server. This service takes a JSON input with the login information and retrieve a JSON output with the session ID.

When using a Rest client, like a chrome extension, everything works.

Now I want to implement it using JS but despite of the failure return, I can not see any details of what is wrong (error messages are blank) and neither could found what I am missing in my code.

```
$.ajax({
    // the URL for the request
    url: "https://host002:50000/b1s/v1/Login",

    // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        UserName: "manager",
        Password: "1234",
        CompanyDB: "CUS_001"
    },

    // whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "POST",

    // the type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",

    // code to run if the request succeeds;
    // the response is passed to the function
    success: function( json ) {
        $( "<h1/>" ).text( json.title ).appendTo( "body" );
        $( "<div class=\"content\"/>").html( json.html ).appendTo( "body" );
    },

    // code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
    // status codes are passed to the function
    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem! " + xhr.responseText);
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
    },

    // code to run regardless of success or failure
    complete: function( xhr, status ) {
        alert( "The request is complete!" );
    }
});
```

xhr.responseText is always blank. Status is always error. errorThrown is always blank as well.

I tried also the $post method but got the same behavior.

Comment: It could be a crossorigin restriction. Is the REST service yours? If so, have you enabled crossorigin requeusts on it?

Comment: Your data object is not JSON.

Comment: I thought about it but as I mentioned, it worked on a REST Client on Chrome/Firefox.  So I believe there should be no crossorigin restriction. And yes, the REST service is on a remote server, on another domain. Tks!

Comment: I believe it works for the extension because the permissions are expressly set in the manifest. If you're using an inspector like Firebug, the response headers should give you some clue in any case.

Comment: I think server returning incorrect JSON response, since your ajax request experting JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect. Try using this

```
data: JSON.stringify({UserName: "manager", Password: "1234", CompanyDB: "CUS_001"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But it is not the cause. After change it i got the very same issue.

Answer (score 0):

While navigating from one url to other there is a cross-domain error thing which pops up.
Try doing this.
Call to a function on your same url using ajax and from there use **CURL** request to your web service url.